# How to configure Jest testing framework for use in Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, nuxt.js

The recommended [Nuxt.js starter template](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app) does not suggest any tool for unit tests.

How can we set and use [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) for unit testing in Nuxt.js?

Answer (score 5):

See nuxt examples repo for example of using jest + vtu:

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/examples/jest-vtu-example

Comment: That is nice. I will check and test that in details during this weekend.

Comment: Wow, why didn't I know about all those hidden super usefull examples before? Am I missing something?

Comment: As an update to this, in that pull request link I had to look for the example, and here is the link as of now. https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/examples/jest-vtu-example